# Trying to paint rectangles inside a swing worker

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have code to create a bunch of vertical rectangles to visualize a sorting algorithm.

```
class MyGUI extends JComponent {
static int rectangleArray[][] = new int[50][2];
boolean populated = false;



public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int margin = 5;
    if (!populated) {
        populate();
        populated = true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rectangleArray.length; i++) {
        if (rectangleArray[i][1] == 0) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else if (rectangleArray[i][1] == 1) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
        } else if (rectangleArray[i][1] == 2) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        g.fillRect (margin, 305 - rectangleArray[i][0], 10, rectangleArray[i][0]);
        margin += 15;
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    insertionSort(); //i want to visually show the swaps here
}


public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 800, 600);
    window.getContentPane().add(new MyGUI());
    window.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

I am trying to basically redraw the canvas after every iteration my insertion sort does. I know I need to put this into a swing worker, and my attempt to do so is here:

```
public class GUIv3 extends JPanel
{
static int rectangleArray[][] = new int[50][2];
boolean populated = false;

private class UpdateTextFieldThread extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer>
{
    static final int THREAD_DELAY = 50;

    protected Void doInBackground()
    {
        //this is the insertion sort code
        for (int i = 0; i < rectangleArray.length; i++) {  
            int value = rectangleArray[i][0];  
            int j = i - 1;  
            while (j >= 0 && rectangleArray[j][0] > value) {  
                rectangleArray[j + 1][0] = rectangleArray[j][0];  
                j = j - 1;  
            }  
            rectangleArray[j + 1][0] = value;  
            //printNumbers(rectangleArray);
            try {
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(THREAD_DELAY);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        } 
        return null;
    }

}

public GUIv3()
{
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 800, 600);
    window.getContentPane().add(new GUIv3());
    window.setVisible(true);
    int margin = 5;
    if (!populated) {
        populate();
        populated = true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rectangleArray.length; i++) {
        //i cant exactly do anything to g since it doesn't exist here...
        if (rectangleArray[i][1] == 0) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else if (rectangleArray[i][1] == 1) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
        } else if (rectangleArray[i][1] == 2) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        g.fillRect (margin, 305 - rectangleArray[i][0], 10, rectangleArray[i][0]);
        margin += 15;
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new GUIv3();
}

    public void populate() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rectangleArray.length; i++) {
        rectangleArray[i][0] = (int)(Math.random() * 300) + 1;
    }
}
}
```

I have commented where I am having an issue. I am lost as to how I can create objects without the paint method that uses Graphics g.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to basically redraw the canvas after every iteration my insertion sort does. I know I need to put this into a swing worker, and my attempt to do so is here:

Heck no. The easiest way to do this is to simply use a Swing Timer. Since you're iterating through the sort one step at a time, the actual single step of sorting should take hardly any processing time at all, and so the Timer should provide you with an adequate delay without having to mess with the mess of creating a SwingWorker or any other direct background thread.

> I am lost as to how I can create objects without the paint method that uses Graphics g.

Easy, just concentrate on sorting **numbers** held by a collection such as an array or ArrayList, and then in your JPanel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, iterate through the array or collection and draw your rectangles based on the numbers found in the collection, and using the Graphics object that the JVM provides to the `paintComponent` override. Don't forget to call the super's method first though so as to erase the previous drawing.

---

**Edit**
You ask:

> How do I implement a swing timer on the paintComponent? Can I get some direction on how to enable a swing timer and perform these overrides?

One does not directly interact with the other.

- You Swing Timer's ActionListener will perform a new step in the sort iteration each time its actionPerformed method is called.
- It will then stuff the a class instance field int array or `ArrayList<Integer>` with the new values,
- And then call `repaint()` on the drawing rectangle.
- This call to `repaint()` will stimulate the painting cascade, *usually* resulting in the JVM calling your drawing JPanel's `paintComponent` method.
- This method will then iterate through the instance field with the numbers and use the numbers to draw the rectangles.
- Again, the paintComponent method does not directly interact with the Timer and isn't even aware of its existence. All it knows to do is to iterate through a collection and draw the visual representation of the collection.
- And the Timer has no direct interaction with the paintComponent method or the Graphics object. All it does is a sort step, stuff the data some place that is available to the drawing code, and then trigger a draw by calling `repaint()`.

Comment: How do I implement a swing timer on the paintComponent? Can I get some direction on how to enable a swing timer and perform these overrides?

Comment: @DCo: see edit to answer for  more specifics. I prefer to leave the actual coding to you as you'll learn much more this way. For the nuts and bolts on how to use a Swing Timer, Google `Java Swing Timer Tutorial` and check out the first hit. Much luck!